# pyspark count not null values for pairs in two column within group

Tags: python, group-by, count, pyspark, null

I have some data like this

```
A    B    C
1   Null  3
1   2     4
2   Null  6
2   2    Null
2   1    2
3   Null 4
```

and I want to groupby A and then calculat the number of rows that don't contain Null value. So, the result should be

```
A    count  
1      1
2      1
3      0
```

I don't think this will work..., does it?

```
df.groupby('A').agg(count('B','C'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use an auxiliary column saying whether B or C is Null. Negative result in this solution and return 1 or 0. And use sum for this column.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, when
# ...
df.withColumn("isNotNull", when(df.B.isNull() | df.C.isNull(), 0).otherwise(1))\
    .groupBy("A").agg(sum("isNotNull"))
```

Demo:

```python
df.show()
# +---+----+----+                                                                 
# | _1|  _2|  _3|
# +---+----+----+
# |  1|null|   3|
# |  1|   2|   4|
# |  2|null|   6|
# |  2|   2|null|
# |  2|   1|   2|
# |  3|null|   4|
# +---+----+----+

df.withColumn("isNotNull", when(df._2.isNull() | df._3.isNull(), 0).otherwise(1)).show()
# +---+----+----+---------+
# | _1|  _2|  _3|isNotNull|
# +---+----+----+---------+
# |  1|null|   3|        0|
# |  1|   2|   4|        1|
# |  2|null|   6|        0|
# |  2|   2|null|        0|
# |  2|   1|   2|        1|
# |  3|null|   4|        0|
# +---+----+----+---------+

df.withColumn("isNotNull", when(df._2.isNull() | df._3.isNull(), 0).otherwise(1))\
  .groupBy("_1").agg(sum("isNotNull")).show()
# +---+--------------+
# | _1|sum(isNotNull)|
# +---+--------------+
# |  1|             1|
# |  3|             0|
# |  2|             1|
# +---+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop rows that contain null values and then `groupby` + `count`:

```py
df.select('A').dropDuplicates().join(
    df.dropna(how='any').groupby('A').count(), on=['A'], how='left'
).show()
+---+-----+
|  A|count|
+---+-----+
|  1|    1|
|  3| null|
|  2|    1|
+---+-----+
```

If you don't want to do the join, create another column to indicate whether there is null in columns B or C:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.selectExpr('*', 
    'case when B is not null and C is not null then 1 else 0 end as D'
).groupby('A').agg(f.sum('D').alias('count')).show()
+---+-----+
|  A|count|
+---+-----+
|  1|    1|
|  3|    0|
|  2|    1|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Hi Psidom, sorry that I forget to update my question. Please take a look at the edited question. I don't really want use join to keep all categories in 'A', but with this procedure, i need to do a left join i think. Thank you.